# Laravel show last reply left on post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to show the last reply that was left on a post. But only the name and date of it. I tried the following things

What I think this one should do is look at the replies to the post. Sort them by ID and then display the first one's username. But it doesn't work.
`$topic->replies->sortBydesc('id')->first()->user->username }}`

I also tried this one where I requested all the replies in the entire forum and displayed the last one. It worked but I wasn't the one related to the post.
`{{ $allposts->sortBydesc('id')->first()->user->username }}`

Does anyone know how I can make this work?
Currently, i'm passing these two into the view (There is nothing wrong with these, they work but I think there should be something added)

```
public function show($id)
{


    $topics = Topic::with('theme')->find($id);
    $theme = Theme::with('topics')->find($id);

    return view('themes.theme')->with('topics', $topics)->with('theme', $theme);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are topic->replies a separate model which is connected by a relationship? If so you would need to eager load those similar to topic->theme.

Comment: I passed the topic to the view, If i do something like `{{ $topic->replies->count() }}` It counts every reply that is connected to that topic, So something like `$topic->replies->sortBydesc('id')->first()->user->username }}` would make sense to me. There is norhing wrong with the relations believe me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get `topic`'s `replies` you need to eager load. Also if you have relation with `user` who replied eager load it as well.

Use `latest()` method for getting latest replies.

For only `name` and `date` we have `select()` .

```
public function show($id)
{
    $topics = $topic->with('replies' => function($query) {
        $query->with('user')->select('name', 'created_at')->latest();
    });
    $theme = Theme::with('topics')->find($id);

    return view('themes.theme', compact('topics', 'theme'));
}
```

Comment: I have to put this is the Controller right? Because it won't let me. It gives me a error

Comment: It just gives a red line between the replies and the arrow and on the word topic.